# C# Grid - Get height of all children

Tags: c#, grid, windows-runtime

I have stumbled upon a minor problem, which leaves me unable to continue my code.
I need to be able to recieve the accumulated height of all children in a grid.

For example: There are 3 children. Each of them has a height of 40, a Top Margin of 5 and a Bot Margin of 5. Which means their height is actually 50x3 = 150 together.

How can I check that height?
I need it for a part of the code:

```
_contentGrid.Height = ??? -> Height of all Children together
```

Why I want that does not matter. Better options do not matter either. I need to recieve this height somehow.

Thank you for your time.

Narakuvera

Answer (score 0):

If they all have the same Height you should look at the ActualHeight-Property:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.actualheight%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
_contentGrid.Height = (ActualHeight+10)*3;
```

Comment: That was just an example. They can all have different heights. Anyways thank you, I'll check it out. :)

Comment: You could also limit the Height if that is an Solution for you.

Comment: It works if all the children have the same height, thanks :) But is there a possibility to make it more dynamic, so I can use elements with different heights?

Comment: Uhm.. Im not sure about that. Give me a second.

Comment: I looked for some useable function that could solve this problem but i didnt find one. If its possible for you to call *.Height on every children, you could do it like this: `(child1.ActualHeight+child2.ActualHeight+child3.ActualHeight)+(10*3)`

Comment: Yeah, I've found nothing either. Calling Height on every child is something I want to prevent. Sometimes the element can contain up to 500 children, which would break the program ^-^

Comment: It seems like that the 2 options you have is Limiting the elements or calling the children. Or write an own controll. The default controlls are shit.

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I'll figure something out with the given options. :)